Address Lookup Table is not compressing address as per expected
Following transaction in devnet
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5FvqJxfoffeBGMwQHh618KzZcNSHCmfdvY4xwNJBsSDyfNEqWpJ9R1FZSWRccyKkrsUDt4ZG3YaZEdvmawHSPT2X?cluster=devnet
The lookup address : https://solana.fm/address/7MBL8iHkarDQwh6BYfaWQxavuFxi5eUVWpNK7WCqrRY9?cluster=devnet-alpha
I have put all signers addresses into lookup table, but it's not being compressed in the transaction.
I can see them as

instead of

Any idea ?
